# Dissociate OpenID with account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

Is there a method to disassociate an OpenID from my account? Currently, my account is associated with my Google account; I wish to create a new one and no longer use my current one as I no longer wish to be associated with some of my older questions. Instead of going through and dissociating myself from several different questions, I think it would be easier to dissociate myself from the account itself. Is there a way to do so?

Note: I could obviously just create a new OpenID and use that to create a new account; I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add any number of openIDs to your account, then you can delete the one you don't want and access it via any of the others.

This can be done via the "My Logins" page in the "Settings" section of the profile page.

[image: Edit Profile & Settings -> My Logins]

Comment: Is there any way to dissociate the last OpenID from the account as well? I.e. leave no remaining logins?

Comment: There shouldn't be, given that if that happens, an account will remain orphaned (and can't be accessed anymore).

Comment: That is what I would like to do. If there is no way to do that, then I can use another account, I guess

Comment: @wolfPack88 you could cons up a new OpenID for the sole purpose of associating it with the existing account.  Add that, remove everything else, and according to this answer that would free up your Google ID to use on a new account.  Otherwise you'd need to a new OpenID for the new account, so doing it this way doesn't seem to cost you anything.  (Plus, if you ever *do* want to get back in later, you'll still have an OpenID to do it with.)